# jquery script not executing after submitting post directly running servlet

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, jsp

I have to work on a demo project where I have created a model for posts in my blog(project). I have to write a jquery script to prevent the default action to go servlet. when I wrote that code jquery worked fine but have some errors in my servlet after removing the errors and re-running the project am facing this issue please help me out.

here is the code that not working.

```
<!-- Add Post JS -->
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       alert("loaded")
      
    $("#add-post").on("submit",function (event) {
        // when the form is submitted 
        alert("clicked")
        event.preventDefault();
        
        // console.log("Submitted")   // For checking its working or not 
        
        let form=new FormData(this);
        // requesting to server
        $.ajax({
            url: "AddPostServlet",
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                // Success
                console.log(data)
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                // Error
                
            },
            processData: false,
            contentType: false
        })
    })
    </script>
```

**screenshots where am facing isssue.**

Post Modal
[image]

after clicking on the post button to don't want to show the servlet page.
After clicking on Post button :
[image]

I just want to after clicking post button form stay on the same page but the servlet works in the background.

For Full Code :
[enter link description here](https://github.com/swapniltake1/TechBlog)

Comment: Swapnil, Can you please include your `Config1.xml` file in the question as well?

Based on the `IOException` caused when parsing the file, I think the issue might have to do with the content of the file.

Comment: can you review it again please bro